# How to get HTTP reply in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, httpresponse

Before I satart, allow me to explain a situation.

1. I have an html(say A.html) page where I get information from a form. I send the data to a php page (say B.php).
2. B.php processes the form and echo a string on screen.
3. A javascript page (Say C.js) needs to send an HTTP request to B.php and read what has been echoed.

Is such a thing even possible? I searched a lot and no explanation.

Comment: Please read up about AJAX

Comment: What you want is probably possible, but it sounds like an x/y problem, one page accessing the result of user action on another page etc. Are you sure you're not just looking for ajax to submit the form and return the result in the background.

Comment: Sounds like you want to make an ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use AJAX.

It concludes 3 steps :

1. Create XMLHttpRequest Object
2. Set onreadystatechange function
3. Post data via JS

File A.html:

```html
<html>
 <input id="text" type="text" value="Hello"/>
 <input type="button" value="getResponse" onclick="getResponse();"/>
 <script>
 var xmlhttp;
 //Create XMLHttpRequest Object
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 //this function will be triggered after "xmlhttp.send" finished
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
  //readyState==4 means success, and status==200 means 'OK'
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
   alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
 }
 // send post data via your web element
 function getResponse(){
  var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
  //send data and get response
  xmlhttp.open("POST","b.php",true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send("text="+text);
 }
 </script>
</html>
```

And the file b.php:

```
<?php 
$text = $_POST['text'];
echo "The length of your text $text is ".strlen($text);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, brilliant ! . However if I change 'b.php' to a www URL , no response is generated ! Why?

Comment: new url should be at the same domain(or IP) with your current page(a.html), because cross-domain visiting is not allowed and unsafety. Just use relative address in the page path parameter.